# How do you send an ajax request every time that a form input field changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

For example, there is an input field.  Every time a user types a key into that field, it sends an AJAX request with whatever text is currently in that input, and does something with it.  I've looked into the change and keyup functions in Jquery, but when I try them in Jsfiddle they don't do anything.  Is there a standard way of doing this type of operation?  I know its common for validations and stuff.

```
<form>
    <input id="test" type='text' >
    <input type="submit" value="asdf">
</form>

$('input').on("change",(function(e){
    alert("Hello");
});
```

The effect I am going for is like this game www.sporcle.com/games/g/nflteams#

You can type in any text and if its within the set of correct answers then the table will update to show that answer. You never have to submit. How do you suppose they achieved this effect?

It seemed to me like they must be querying the database every time a user enters a key, to see if it is a correct answer.  If it is they update the table to display the answer.  What are other ways to do this?

Comment: What exactly did you try?

Comment: keyup should work. Code?

Comment: yeah what did you try and jsfiddle is not the best place to tedt if you want to try ajax calls with your server

Comment: I didn't try ajax calls, I just tried using the jquery event to see if it actually fired off.  I'll edit with the code

Answer (score 13):

sending a request on each change is just bad, delay the ajax on the last change

```
var changeTimer = false;

$("your inputs").on("your change event",function(){
        if(changeTimer !== false) clearTimeout(changeTimer);
        changeTimer = setTimeout(function(){
            /* your ajax here */
            changeTimer = false;
        },300);
});
```

Comment: Alternatively, take a look at using jquery-debounce or underscore's debounce function. It's pretty simple, you don't need to add underscore as a dependency, just modify the method where a couple underscore function. http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-83

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably do something similar to this.
you'd have to add some extra code to handle dropdowns, but the idea is the same.

```
$('form input').keyup(function () {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: data,
      success: success,
      dataType: dataType
    });
});
```

Comment: +1 if its keyup, as this will return the most recent value...  keypress() will leave you one character behind.

Comment: good call, ty, i use keyup in my own projects, just forgot :)

Comment: @DylanHayes is it true that this is not the best approach?  Will this not work at scale?  If so, what is a superior way to validate

Comment: it depends what you want to do.  I've never had issues using this type of validation. Autocomplete text boxes, like the main search box on amazon.com use this same type of logic to fetch what it "thinks" you are trying to type. You could always scale it back to validate on "change" event if you want a one time validation, but ive never had to scale back.

Answer (score 1):

Just make an `$.ajax()` call every time the change event is fired! Like so:

```
$(document).on('keydown','input',function(){
    $.ajax({
        // options here
    });
});
```

***Whilst the above will help achieve what you want, I must advise that it is not great practice to fire off constant AJAX requests as this can put a huge load on the server if you have a lot of traffic. You would be better off either validating every n seconds, or validating client side, or validating on submission...***

**UPDATE**

It appears you do not want to catch the `change` event, you would like to know when anything is entered. Resultantly, I have changed my code to catch the `keydown` event. This will fire whenever a key is pressed down whilst focused on an input.

Comment: The effect I am going for is like this game http://www.sporcle.com/games/g/nflteams#

You can type in any text and if its within the set of correct answers then the table will update to show that answer.  You never have to submit.  How do you suppose they achieved this effect?

Comment: yours doesn't do what the user is asking, yours will only fire on change. Advisable or not, it's not answering the question.

Comment: @DylanHayes Fair point, I have altered my code to catch the `keydown` event.

Comment: but the real problem here is the constant ajax call, +1 for point it

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#yourInputId').keyup (function () {
    $.post('http://yoururl.com', { value: $(this).val() }).done(function (data) {
        $('#feedbackDivId').html(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: please indent, and .html(done) will do an error, try with .html(data)