# JQUERY ajax post - multiple click, one reload - it is possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a problem and I don't know what is the solution. I would like to reload the specified divs only once after multiple click. Now when I add new item to the database from dropdown input, then after each click each time reload the specified div, and sometimes it is very disturbing. When you want to select a new item from the list, and then suddenly reset, and you need to select again). How can I do that if I click to add new item (sometimes I select 4-5 new items - not multiple select!) then not refresh the specified div after each click, just once with a specified delay.

Here is the current code of the javascript part (now it refresh after 100 milliseconds after a new item added). I hope that someone could help me, or give me an idea how can I resolve this.  Many thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">   

 $('body').on('click',".addhplayer",function() {

 var absidplayer = $('#abshidplayer').find(":selected").val();
 var abstype = $('#abshtype').find(":selected").val();
 var obj = $(this); // first store $(this) in obj
 var absseasonid = $(this).attr('data-absseasonid');
 var absidclub = $(this).attr('data-absidclub');
 var absidmatch = $(this).attr('data-absidmatch');
 
 
//var dataString = 'abstype=' + abstype + '&addplayer=1&' + 'absidplayer=' + absidplayer + '&' + 'absidclub=' + absidclub + '&' + 'absidmatch=' + absidmatch + '&' + 'absseasonid=' + absseasonid;
$.ajax({
    url: 'edit_absence.php',
    type: 'POST',
    timeout: 100,
    data: {
        addtype: abstype,
        addhplayer: '1',
        addidplayer: absidplayer,
        addidclub: absidclub,
        addidmatch: absidmatch,
        addseasonid: absseasonid
    },
    success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR){
     $('.hpstatus').show();
        $(".hpstatus").load(" .hpstatus");
    $('#injur').show();
   $("#injur").load(" #injur");
   
       $("#homelineups").load(" #homelineups");
   $("#awaylineups").load(" #awaylineups");
  
},
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out my old response to this question :
[How do you send an ajax request every time that a form input field changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16627964/how-do-you-send-an-ajax-request-every-time-that-a-form-input-field-changes/16628110#16628110)

basically wrap your event code to a delayed function, on multiple call it will cancel the previous planned ajax call if the delay is not reach

edit > on your particular code :

```
  var changeTimer = false;
    
  function yourSpecificEventCode(){
    var absidplayer = $('#abshidplayer').find(":selected").val();
    var abstype = $('#abshtype').find(":selected").val();
    var $o = $(this); // first store $(this) in obj
    var absseasonid = $o.attr('data-absseasonid');
    var absidclub = $o.attr('data-absidclub');
    var absidmatch = $o.attr('data-absidmatch');
     
    $.ajax({
        url: 'edit_absence.php',
        type: 'POST',
        timeout: 100,
        data: {
            addtype: abstype,
            addhplayer: '1',
            addidplayer: absidplayer,
            addidclub: absidclub,
            addidmatch: absidmatch,
            addseasonid: absseasonid
        },
        success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR){
          $('.hpstatus').show().load(" .hpstatus");
          $('#injur').show().load(" #injur");
          $("#homelineups").load(" #homelineups");
          $("#awaylineups").load(" #awaylineups");
        },
    });
  }
    
  $('body').on('click',".addhplayer",function() {
          if(changeTimer !== false) clearTimeout(changeTimer);
          let t = this ;
          changeTimer = setTimeout(function(){
              yourSpecificEventCode.call( t ) ;
              changeTimer = false;
          },300);
  });
```

Comment: I checked your link, but I don't know how could I modify my code to cancel the previous planned ajax call if the delay is not reach. Could someone to help me to modify my code? I need only that if there is multiple clicks, then only after last click will be ONLY ONE div reloading. Many thanks!

Comment: @Terminus see my edit, just wrapped your code

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will try. It will be huge help because I am struggling with this problem since long time ago.

Comment: no problem, glad to help, check my edit about give current "this" to your function

Comment: Hi again, I have try your code, but there is a problem: absseasonid, absidclub and absidmatch haven't posted with the ajax request. I don't know what is the problem with them, I guess the function don't care with inputs with data attributes. What do you think, what is the problem? Thanks for the help and for the patience.

Comment: @Terminus, must be a scope problem with "this", now excluded it from the callback, check the edit